# How to show that the isotropic tensor of order $n$ is a multiple of the Kronecker delta?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices, kronecker-symbol

I have already found this question here but with the property of invariant under rotation.  However, I don't have this property and I want to prove that $T_{ij} = \alpha \delta _{ij}$ where $T_{ij}$ are the components of a Cartesian tensor of order $2$ and the tensor is isotropic meaning that $T_{ij} = q_{ik}q_{jl}T_{kl}$ for all $(q_{ij}) \in \mbox{SO}(3)$ where $\mbox{SO}(3)$ is the special orthogonal group of $3 \times 3$ matrices.

Comment: what broader subject area is considered to be?

Comment: Thanks for your edit @Normal Human

Comment: What is $q_{ik}$?

Comment: I have edited the question @martini

Comment: That's a duplicate, but the original hasn't an accepted(!) answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881571/how-to-prove-that-the-kronecker-delta-is-the-unique-isotropic-tensor-of-order-2

Comment: I know that this questions is similar to the one you mentioned, but as you said, there is not an accepted answer and also there is a difference in the question since I don't have the property of invariance.

Comment: You **have** this property, expressed by $T_{ij} = \sum_{k,l} q_{ik}q_{jl}T_{kl}$ (for all $q \in {\rm SO}(3)$, that is, the *rotations*), just see how this property is used in the answer to the other question.

Comment: Okay i will try this thank you very much.@martini

Comment: is the answer of the other question accepted ? because it is really confusing

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881571/how-to-prove-that-the-kronecker-delta-is-the-unique-isotropic-tensor-of-order-2) where we do not have only ${\rm SO}(3)$, but ${\rm O}(3)$-invariance:

- First we will show, that $T$ has to be diagonal, for this consider the transform, for $1 \le j \le 3$: 
  $$ (q^j)_{kl} = \begin{cases}   1 & k=j, l=j\\
                                 -1 & k\ne j, l \ne j, k = l\\
                                 0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  $$
  for example $q^1$ is given by 
  $$ q^1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  Then $q^j$ is orthogonal and has determinant $1$, hence $q^j \in {\rm SO}(3)$. Now we have to compute $(q^j)^tTq^j$, but as $q^j$ is symmetric, $(q^j)^t = q^j$. We will do it for $j=1$, the other cases are analogous 
  \begin{align*}
    q^1Tq^1 &=  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}T \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\\
       &=  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} T_{11} & -T_{12} & -T_{13}\\ T_{21} & -T_{22} & -T_{23}\\
                  T_{31} & -T_{32} & -T_{33} \end{pmatrix}\\
       &= \begin{pmatrix} T_{11} & -T_{12} & -T_{13}\\ -T_{21} & T_{22} & T_{23} \\ -T_{31} & T_{32} & T_{33} \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align*}
  As this equals $T$, we can read off: 
  $$ T_{12} = -T_{12}, T_{21} = -T_{21}, T_{13} = -T_{13}, T_{31} = -T_{31} $$
  hence $T_{12} = T_{21} = T_{13} = T_{31} = 0$. By looking at $q^2$, $q^3$, we see that the other off-diagonal elements of $T$ have to be 0 too. So $T$ is diagonal.
- Knowing that $T$ is diagonal, we will show, that all diagonal entries are equal, for that consider another $q^j$, namely 
  $$ (q^j)_{kl} = \begin{cases}   1 & k=j, l=j\\
                                 1 & k\ne j, l \ne j, k \ne l\\
                                 0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  $$
  for example $q^1$ is given by 
  $$ q^1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  Again, $q^j \in {\rm SO}(3)$ is symmetric, hence we have $q^jTq^j = T$, computing gives (we will use that $T$ is diagonal!): 
  \begin{align*}
    q^1Tq^1 &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}T\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\\
      &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} T_{11} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & T_{22} \\ 0 & T_{33} & 0 \end{pmatrix}\\
     &= \begin{pmatrix} T_{11} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & T_{33} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & T_{22} \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align*}
  Hence, as this is $T$, $T_{22} = T_{33}$. Using $q^2$, $q^3$, gives $T_{11} = T_{22} = T_{33}$, or $T_{ij} = \alpha \delta_{ij}$.